# Why is my WinForms application not receiving a click from PostMessage?

Tags: c#, winforms, click

When trying to click inside of a WebView2 instance using PostMessage, the window does not react.

Using the `ClickWindow` method below,

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
public const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

public struct RECT
{
   public int Left;        
   public int Top;         
   public int Right;       
   public int Bottom;      
}
public void ClickWindow(string windowName, int x, int y)
{
    // Find the window by name
    IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, windowName);

    // Get the window's rectangle
    RECT rect = new RECT();
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);

    // Calculate absolute x and y
    int absoluteX = rect.Left + x;
    int absoluteY = rect.Top + y;

    // Send the mouse down and up messages
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, (absoluteY << 16) + absoluteX);
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, (absoluteY << 16) + absoluteX);
}
```

I have successfully clicked buttons inside of a firefox window, but when I try to use it on my winforms application, it does not work.
Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:** I have changed the above code to the following. Using WinSpy++, I've found out that some child windows will receive a click, but only very rarely. Below I have it randomly picking one of these windows and clicking it.

```cs
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rect lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

#pragma warning disable CS0649
    public struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
#pragma warning restore CS0649

    private void ClickWindow(int relativeX, int relativeY)
    {
        // Find the window by name
        var ran = new Random().Next(4);
        var hwnd = Central.WebView2.Handle;
        if (ran > 1)
            hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_WidgetWin_0", IntPtr.Zero);
        if (ran > 2)
            hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", IntPtr.Zero);
        if (ran > 3)
            hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", IntPtr.Zero);

        // Get the window's rectangle
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, out var rect);

        // Calculate absolute x and y
        var absoluteX = rect.Left + relativeX;
        var absoluteY = rect.Top + relativeY;

        // Send the mouse down and up messages
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, (absoluteY << 16) + absoluteX);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, (absoluteY << 16) + absoluteX);
    }
```

Comment: When you want to *automate* some windows, probably better use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) -- It's unfortunate that Chrome / Edge / Firefox all use a slightly different model (mostly in relation to managed [UIAutomation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)), but the basics are not that different. If you just need to click a button, it's almost the same thing for all

Comment: @Jimi That seems very heavyweight for my task. All I'm attempting to do is click in this one spot every so often.

Comment: Did you check if `hwnd` and `rect` are getting valid values? Did you try with other components on the form?

Comment: After doing some more research, it seems that I can only click on certain webpages inside of firefox.

Comment: @NPras I have updated the post with my findings.